# XML validator.w3.org always reports error on second character <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: php, xml, validation, utf-8, rss

The W3C validator site complains about the question mark in the very first line. The error looks ridiculous because it's literally the second character of the XML and I'm staring directly at a question mark. It spits out:

```
Sorry

This feed does not validate.

line 1, column 1: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1:1: not well-formed (invalid token) [help]

    ﻿﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>            
     ^
```

Might be important, I tried removing the  and then receive:

```
This feed does not validate.

line 1, column 1: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1:1: not well-formed (invalid token) [help]

    ﻿﻿xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"            
     ^
```

This can be seen on http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmetaseries.com%2Ffeed_test.php%3Fseries_id%3D3

It seems like the validator does not like the second character. As far as I know the document is converted to UTF-8 without BOM. Firefox likes the feed and displays it properly. I don't understand what the validator is telling me.

Comment: Chrome doesn't like it tho. `error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not one but **two** UTF-8 BOMs at the front of your page.

I did a `wget` followed by an `od -c` and this is what came out:

```
0000000 357 273 277 357 273 277   <   ?   x   m   l       v   e   r   s
0000020   i   o   n   =   "   1   .   0   "       e   n   c   o   d   i
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. 2 include files were spitting it out, so my check of the initial page was not doing me any good. Working now.

Answer (score 2):

You send **two BOMs** before the first visible character. This is not allowed.

Opera’s error message is better:

> unexpected text (non-whitespace text outside root element)

Looking at the source with a hex viewer will show you the BOMs.